# Testing hypothesis using the Neyman-Pearson Lemma

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, parameter-estimation

[image: Information]

This is the information I have, I want to test the hypotheses $H_0$ : λ = λ0 against the alternative hypotheses $H_0$ : λ = λ1,
where λ1 > λ0.

I want to do this by using the Neyman–Pearson Lemma, and that rejecting $H_0$ if M < t is a most powerful test, where M =∑ $X_k$. ( if M < t we reject, not accept).

So far I've calculated the likelihood ratio as:

$\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_0}∑^n_{k=1}x^{n(d-1)}e^{-∑^n_{k=1}x(\lambda_1-\lambda_0)}$

How do I go from here with regards to the most powerful test?

Comment: Where is a sample $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ in your likelihood ratio?

Comment: My apologies @NCh I forgot to add this in, I've edited them in

Comment: What is $\lambda_2$? What is $x$? There is no $x$ in your task. Try to write likelihood functions separately.

Comment: Sorry @NCh $\lambda_2$ was a typo, it was supposed to be $\lambda_0$, I guess I've been doing maths a bit too long. So if I write out the likelihood functions separately as $\frac{\lambda_1}{\lambda_0}$ would that make it easier for me to do?

Comment: Likelihood function $L_\lambda(X_1,\ldots,X_n)=P_\lambda(X_1)\cdot P_\lambda(X_2) \cdot\ldots \cdot P_\lambda(X_n)$ and nothing else.

Comment: The Likelihood Function I calculated earlier was $\frac{\lambda^{dn}}{(d-1)!^n}∑^n_{k=1}x^{n(d-1)}e^{-\lambda ∑^n_{k=1}x}$ is this incorrect?

Comment: This is incorrect. Where is a sample in your likelihood function?

Comment: That is all the information I have to work with I believe @NCh

Comment: Given $P_\lambda(x)$, can you write $P_\lambda(X_1)$? Then $P_\lambda(X_2)$ and so on.